# Is there any way to specify User permissions inside a Jquery datatable which is being rendered via server side processing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables, user-permissions

I am trying to implement server side processing to some of my tables which carry a huge amount of data.
I am almost done with it but as i am amending an already created project there is a requirement which i have to follow. i have to show certain options based on certain logged in users inside the table.

Now the code for options i get that but is there any way that i might apply some conditions on this javascript code for jquery datatables? For example if i only want admin user access to Eidt and delete button how would i render this code? I Just can not figure this out.

```
{
            "data": null,
            "render": function (value) {
                return '<a href="/RecipeIngredients/Details/' + renderDT_RowId(value.dT_RowId) + '"button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Details</a> <br> '
                    + '<a href="/RecipeIngredients/Edit/' + renderDT_RowId(value.dT_RowId) + '"button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Edit </a> <br> '
                    + '<a href="/RecipeIngredients/Delete/' + renderDT_RowId(value.dT_RowId) + '"button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Delete</a>';
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any sort of help :)

Comment: One option: You can add some data to the JSON [response](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) from the server - for example, `"isAdmin": true` (or `false)`. You can then use that new data in a DataTables [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) function to modify the JSON table data before it is displayed by DataTables.

Comment: Side note: Instead of using something like `renderDT_RowId(value.dT_RowId)` in a column renderer, you can use `render( data, type, row, meta ) { ... }` - and the `row` variable will give you access to every value in the current row, including (I assume) the row ID you want to use in those links you are building.